# Is there a hotkey for Docking Controls in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i'm constantly docking controls and panels in my designer and was wondering if there is some cntrl + hotkey key combination i could do to set a control to `full dock` or `Top Dock`

Comment: **Do you have a programming issue?**

Comment: yes this affects the amount of time i get to do programming in a day

Comment: Tried searching through this page? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx  And if it's not built into Visual Studio, you may want to look into AutoHotKey - http://ahkscript.org/